# Partition setup in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are having few tables with partitions and we don't know how to get the partition keys for a specific table.

How can I get or view the partition key set up in oracle database for a specific table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find that information here:

```
select * from USER_PART_TABLES;
select * from USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS;
```

[Source.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin005.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check out all the below data dictionary views,

```
ALL_PART_KEY_COLUMNS
DBA_PART_KEY_COLUMNS
USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS
```

There is also a view called `ALL_SUBPART_KEY_COLUMNS`.